# how to get username form django session

Tags: django

i am trying to get user name from session by using **request.user** but i am getting AnonymousUser, how do i get user name

```
def login_two(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      uname = request.POST.get('name2')
      pwd = request.POST.get('password2')

      check_user = User.objects.filter(username=uname, password=pwd)
      if check_user:
         request.session['user'] = uname
         return redirect('index')

  return render(request, 'login2.html')
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: If the `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser`, then it means the user has not logged in.

Comment: I would advise that you use Django's authentication system. You can tailor this towards a custom user model as described in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: actually i follow this to create user https://dev.to/madhubankhatri/django-login-logout-using-sessions-2d9i

Comment: please do *not* use this. This tutorial does not even hash the password, and thus has a *severe* security problem.